# Show the inequality $\log(k)\log(n-k)<\log^2(n/2)$ holds

Tags: inequality

How to show $\log(k)\log(n-k)<\log^2(n/2)$, for all $n,k >3$, where log is the natural log.

I plotted the function $\log(k)\log(n-k)-\log^2(n/2)$ and found the values are all negative, but I don't know how to show it.

Comment: Hint: $\log\log x$ is concave.

Comment: Another hint: $(k + (n-k))/2 = n/2$.

Comment: the first hint you mean the log of log x?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: maybe tell me a little bit more? I can't figure it out.

Comment: @Unit Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Using AM-GM and Jensen's inequalities:
$$\sqrt{\log k \cdot \log (n-k)} \le \frac{\log k + \log (n-k)}2  \le \log\frac{n}2$$
Equality is possible when $k = \dfrac{n}2$, so the inequality should not be strict.